# ArrayList with custom class to jList

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, arraylist

I have ArrayList  of Children and has  a few  properties ( full name (String),age(int),parent_id(int),id(int)).
I'm using netbeans design view to create JFrame ( it's more easy for me to position elements).

In this  JFRAME I have jList  how I can  set all rows from ArrayList at  jList and format like  that :

`String.format("%s \t %d",ch.getFullName(),ch.getAge())`.

I tried to make it foreach element from arraylist but doesnt work.

Comment: Insufficient details, try to add more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add all the Children classes to the `JList` model and define a custom `ListCellRenderer`. In the renderer get value and use the Children element to set text.

Comment: `public void loadKids(ArrayList<Children> childs) {
        final String[] tmpData = new String[childs.size()];
        for (Children ch : childs) {
        }
        listKids.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
           // String[] strings = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"};
            @Override
            public int getSize() {
                return tmpData.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getElementAt(int i) {
                return tmpData[i];
            }
        });

    }`

Comment: This is the way I try to load arrayList in  jList. Doesnt work.

Comment: Use DefaultListModel passing your array of Children. To simplify override toString() method of Children to return name+"\t"+age

Answer (score 1):

A JTable is a better choice for rendering multiple columns of data. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

The DefaultTableModel doesn't support an ArrayList with custom Objects so you could try using the [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/).